# Login over AJAX, use cookie in MVC + Angular. CORS

Tags: angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cors, aspnetboilerplate

I have to separate aspnetboilerplate (Asp.Net MVC + AngularJS frontend) Web from API part and authenticate users in AngularJS + ASP.Net MVC simultaneously. This works on single domain. Does not work when API is hosted on another server.

My MVC AccountController action Login:

```
AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = rememberMe }, identity);
return Json(new AjaxResponse {Success = true, TargetUrl = Request.ApplicationPath });
```

My Login.js file:

```
    $("#LoginButton").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        abp.ui.setBusy(
            $("#LoginArea"),
            abp.ajax({
                url: "http://internallyAccesibleServer/Account/Login",
                //url: abp.appPath + "Account/Login",
                type: "POST",
                crossDomain: true,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    tenancyName: $("#TenancyName").val(),
                    usernameOrEmailAddress: $("#EmailAddressInput").val(),
                    password: $("#PasswordInput").val(),
                    rememberMe: false
                })
            })
            .done(function(response) {
                abp.message.info("Login succeeded");})
            .fail(function(data) {
                abp.message.error(data.details, data.message);
            })
        );
    });
```

When I run this on hxxp://internallyAccesibleServer/ - log in succeeds and I can access authorized resurces over AngularJS. 
If I run the same Login.js code from any **otherserver** - I see a "Login succeeded" message for a moment (also I see a database / log record on my internallyAccesibleServer - so AJAX request is working fine) and then comes HTTP response 302, witch is converted from 401 by MVC framework and URL in Location header is "hxxp://otherserver/account/login" - so the origin of request.

My Web.config about CORS:

```
<httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS" />
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, x-xsrf-token" />
    </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

I believe this has something to do with cookie sharing between AJAX and MVC. Can someone please help me to overcome this issue, or should I start to rewrite the GUI in full Angular without any MVC Razor views and use other authentification type, like Bearer? 
Full application is already developed using Razor views :-(

I have read all the related forum.aspnetboilerplate.com messages, but there are no answers to this exact question. Sorry if the links will expire - adding topic name for reference.

DISTRIBUTED WEBAPI AND MVC SITE
hxxps://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=871

DEPLOY ABP ON 3 TIER
hxxps://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2376

3-TIER DEPLOYMENT. SEPARATE GUI FROM APPLICATION
hxxps://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=3301

Very similar problem (but no solution):
hxxps://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747413/sending-cookie-cross-domain-with-cors-using-jquery-hosted-with-mvc-troubleshoo

I have also tried with no luck to implement my own WebClient in .Web layer and expose a cookie to subsequent AJAX calls. What is the best approach to let AJAX call to authenticate in browser?

P.S. this is my OWIN startup configuration addressing auth:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            CookieHttpOnly = false,
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Account/Logout"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnApplyRedirect = ctx =>
                {
                    if (!IsAjaxRequest(ctx.Request))
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

I would be very grateful for any answers.

Comment: Cookie-based authentication doesn't work cross-origin, because cookies are always domain-bound, regardless of your CORS settings.

Comment: I kind-of thought so :-( Thank you for you answer.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps here:

**Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API 2**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Enabling CORS Globally
The method described above can also be used to enable across the API without annotating each controller:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var corsAttr = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://example.com", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(corsAttr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the issue here is that the cookies are not sent to the browser.
To solve that you need first to add the following header to tell the browser to expose the response to your frontend JS code.

`<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />`

Then in you login JS code you need to use the

> XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials

property to enable cross-site requests using cookies. You can do something like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://internallyAccesibleServer/Account/Login",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            tenancyName: $("#TenancyName").val(),
            usernameOrEmailAddress: $("#EmailAddressInput").val(),
            password: $("#PasswordInput").val(),
            rememberMe: false
        }),
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
```

About the redirection. According to ABP [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Javascript-API/AJAX?searchKey=ajax%20abp), if the targetUrl property is set on the response then it redirects to it.